# How to prepend AES ciphertext with IV

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, encryption, cryptography, aes

There seems to be a convention in which an IV can be stored in plaintext in the beginning of an AES encrypted file.

I can encrypt and decrypt a file successfully when providing both the key and the IV during both encryption and decryption. This uses the code below, with slight modification. If that code would help, please LMK and I'll add it.

However, **if I try to write the IV to the beginning of the file in plain text**, I cannot decrypt the content (not sure if it's really being encrypted right either).

Can someone point out what's wrong below? Not sure why the .NET framework doesn't have this a a built in option.

If anyone can point out ways in which I'm not following the aforementioned convention, please do point them out!

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

public class AESBase : IDisposable
{
    protected AesManaged AES;
    protected ICryptoTransform CryptoTransform;

    public AESBase(byte[] key, byte[] iv = null)
    {
        AES = new AesManaged
        {
            BlockSize = 128,
            KeySize = 256,
            Mode = CipherMode.CBC,
            Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7,
            Key = key
        };

        if (iv != null) { AES.IV = iv; }
    }
}

using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

internal class AESFiles : AESBase, IFileCrytpo
{
    internal AESFiles(byte[] key, byte[] iv) : base(key, iv) { }

    #region internal methods

    public void Encrypt(string inputFileName, string outputFileName, bool overwriteFile)
    {
        CryptoTransform = AES.CreateEncryptor(AES.Key, AES.IV);

        if (overwriteFile)
        {
            DeleteFile(outputFileName);
        }

        Transform(inputFileName, outputFileName, true);
    }

    public void Decrypt(string inputFileName, string outputFileName, bool overwriteFile)
    {
        CryptoTransform = AES.CreateDecryptor(AES.Key, AES.IV);

        if (overwriteFile)
        {
            DeleteFile(outputFileName);
        }

        Transform(inputFileName, outputFileName, false);
    }

    #endregion public methods

    #region private methods

    private void Transform(string inputFileName, string outputFileName, bool encrypt)
    {
        var destination = new FileStream(outputFileName, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
        if (encrypt)
        {
            //put the IV unencrypted in the front of the string
            destination.Write(AES.IV, 0, AES.BlockSize / 8);
        }

        var source = new FileStream(inputFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
        if (!encrypt)
        {
            source.Read(AES.IV, 0, AES.BlockSize / 8);
            //var temp = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(AES.IV);
        }

        Transform(source, destination, CryptoTransform);
    }

    private static void Transform(Stream inputStream, Stream outputStream, ICryptoTransform transform)
    {
        using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(outputStream, transform, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            //inputStream.Position = AES.BlockSize/8 + 1; CryptographicException : Length of the data to decrypt is invalid.
            //inputStream.Position = AES.BlockSize/8; CryptographicException : Padding is invalid and cannot be removed.

            inputStream.CopyTo(cryptoStream);
            cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
        }
    }

    private static void DeleteFile(string fileName)
    {
        if (File.Exists(fileName))
        {
            File.Delete(fileName);
        }
    }

    #endregion private methods
}

[TestFixture]
class AESFilesTest
{
    private const string Path = @"C:\Users\Joe\Desktop\";
    private const string FileInput = "Input.csv";
    private const string FileEncrypted = "Encrypted.csv"; 
    private const string FileDecrypted = "Decrypted.csv";

    private readonly string _fileContents = String.Format("Test3,Test4" + Environment.NewLine, "Test5,Test6");

    private readonly byte[] _key;
    private readonly byte[] _iv;

    private readonly Engine _engine;

    public AESFilesTest()
    {
        _engine = new Engine();
        _key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("CEC520FA51EA0A47E87295FA32442605"); //test key
        _iv = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("FB423A0BCB2AF4A4"); //test iv

        File.WriteAllText(Path + FileInput, _fileContents);
    }

    [Test]
    public void decrypted_text_matches_original()
    {
        const string inputFileWithPath = Path + FileInput;

        _engine.Encrypt(_key, _iv, inputFileWithPath, Path + FileEncrypted, true);
        _engine.Decrypt(_key, Path + FileEncrypted, Path + FileDecrypted, true);

        var decrypted = File.ReadAllText(Path + FileDecrypted);
        Console.WriteLine(decrypted);

        Assert.AreEqual(_fileContents, decrypted);
    }
```

Comment: Why not just use serialization and deserialization with help of `CryptoStream` ? Not to mention that storing IV as plain text in a file can cause a possible security issues...

Comment: I have a requirement to store the IV within the file. Can I use the Cryptostream class to serialize and deserialize while storing the IV within the file?

Comment: Storing the IV in the file will not cause security issues.  As Bruce Schneier points out, every crypto block except the last one is completely analogous to the IV -- what the IV is to the first block, the first block (in crypto form, in plain view of everyone) is to the second block and so on.  If anyone needs their IV to be hidden for security purposes, it would be good to rework the entire system.

Comment: But the serialization is a good idea.  You open a FileStream and write your IV into it.  Then you might get away with keeping that FileStream open or you may have to close it and open a new one on the same file in Append mode.  Then write your plaintext to the FileStream via the CryptoStream and you're golden.  A different approach that is acceptable but seems less common is to randomly generate a block of bytes and prepend it to your plaintext before encrypting.  Then encrypt with your IV and you can throw the IV away.  When they decrypt, the first block is junk but everything else is good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There were many errors... The correct code:

```
private void Transform(string inputFileName, string outputFileName, bool encrypt)
{
    using (var source = new FileStream(inputFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
    using (var destination = new FileStream(outputFileName, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
    {
        ICryptoTransform cryptoTransform;

        if (encrypt)
        {
            //put the IV unencrypted in the front of the string
            destination.Write(AES.IV, 0, AES.BlockSize / 8);
            cryptoTransform = AES.CreateEncryptor(AES.Key, AES.IV);
        }
        else
        {
            byte[] bytes = new byte[AES.BlockSize / 8];
            source.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            AES.IV = bytes;
            cryptoTransform = AES.CreateDecryptor(AES.Key, AES.IV);
        }

        Transform(source, destination, cryptoTransform, encrypt);
    }
}

private static void Transform(Stream inputStream, Stream outputStream, ICryptoTransform transform, bool encrypt)
{
    using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(encrypt ? outputStream : inputStream, transform, encrypt ? CryptoStreamMode.Write : CryptoStreamMode.Read))
    {
        //inputStream.Position = AES.BlockSize/8 + 1; CryptographicException : Length of the data to decrypt is invalid.
        //inputStream.Position = AES.BlockSize/8; CryptographicException : Padding is invalid and cannot be removed.

        if (encrypt)
        {
            inputStream.CopyTo(cryptoStream);
            // Not needed. Done by the Dispose()
            //cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
        }
        else
        {
            cryptoStream.CopyTo(outputStream);
        }
    }
}
```

then remove the now useless

```
protected ICryptoTransform CryptoTransform;
```

In general, the handling of the encrypt and of the decrypt operation are totally different... In many places the parameters change.

Another problem was in the reading of the `IV`: you can't read directly into the `IV` property of `AesManaged`, you have to read to a temporary buffer (`bytes`) and then assign the buffer to `IV`.

Third problem: you have to create the `CryptoTransform` when you have the `Key` and the `IV` and you know if you want to encrypt or decrypt.

Ah... and note that you aren't writing the *plain text* IV, because the IV isn't text, it is binary. You are writing the IV in binary format (or in its native format... or whatever you want to call it). Unless with *plaintext* you meant the non-encrypted IV. Then yes, you are writing the *plaintext* version of it. But still you can't encode it with `Encoding.UTF8`, because it isn't a "text"... It is binary data.

Comment: `cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();` isn't required (the `CryptoStream` is always closed), and `byte[] bytes = new byte[16];` should of course be `byte[] bytes = new byte[AES.BlockSize / 8];`. *plaintext* in the cryptographic sense is the input (binary or otherwise) for ciphers. It's the opposite of *ciphertext*. So here *plaintext* simply means "not encrypted". So the last "Ah..." should probably be removed :)

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Considering that there was a `var temp = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(AES.IV);`, I'm not sure what he meant with Plaintext. For the `AES.BlockSize / 8` yes, you are right, but AES has a fixed block length of 16 bytes (for any size of the key), so even that isn't a problem. For the `FlushFinalBlock` you are right. The `Dispose()` calls it internally.